# (Next Cloud) Error while trying to create admin user

Tags: nextcloud

When I was trying to install Next Cloud on a web host server. I get this error message when finally creating the admin account and configuring the database information.

> Error while trying to create admin user: An exception occurred while
>   executing 'CREATE TABLE oc_migrations (app VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
>   version VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(app, version)) DEFAULT
>   CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin ENGINE = InnoDB': SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max
>   key length is 1000 bytes

Maybe there is a way to fix this problem. I am using InfinityFree.net as web host to test next cloud.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From [Nextcloud's installation manual](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/installation/system_requirements.html#database-requirements-for-mysql-mariadb):

> The following is currently required if you’re running Nextcloud together with a MySQL / MariaDB database:
>
> - InnoDB storage engine (MyISAM is not supported)

From InfinityFree's [knowledge base](https://infinityfree.net/support/innodb-on-free-hosting/):

> It’s not possible to create InnoDB tables. The InnoDB storage engine for MySQL is not supported on InfinityFree. Only the MyISAM storage engine can be used.
>
> If your script requires the InnoDB storage engine, you need to [upgrade your account](https://infinityfree.net/premium).

If you do decide to get a premium account, then you'll also need to make sure that `innodb_large_prefix` is enabled in their `my.cnf` file.

Comment: so, there is no other free option?